# Separating embedded system functionality into RTOS tasks

Tags: c, embedded, arm, powerpc, rtos

I am trying to get a good grasp on how to design RTOS tasks to perform the functions needed for an embedded system.  What are some recommended resources for learning concrete guidelines for task design?  Below are some of the typical questions I am trying to answer:

- Should tasks be designed per system module (Flash, USB, Display, etc.) or per system hardware/peripherals (UART, SPI, I2C, etc.) or some mixture of both?  If both, how to decide?
- For serial communication, does it make sense to have a separate task for both Rx and Tx? What are the advantages/disadvantages of this?

I would like to keep the number of tasks to a minimum, but I don't mind increasing the number of tasks if it simplifies design or helps to avoid future pitfalls. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Potential designs are very hardware-specific.  If you only have 16k or RAM in your controller, you probably cannot afford 12 stacks.  What do you have?

Comment: Also, do you need, or intend to allow, nested interrupts?

Comment: @Martin James - currently using ARM Cortex-M3 and M4 with 256K and 512K RAM.  Both have nested interrupts.

Answer (score 3):

Tasks can serve two purposes:

1. Functional partitioning
2. Real-time response

The first can be achieved on any scheduling algorithm - not just real time.  It can be used ot achieve high cohesion and low coupling.  These are concepts common to modular programming with or without threading.

The second aim is specific to an RTOS, and may involve a single "function" as might be conceived in (1) needing to be split into multiple threads in order to meet real-time deadlines.  Here the partitioning into tasks is not the only issue, but also the allocation of thread priorities.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as a rough guide, you can probably get away with only one thread to handle the driving of all slow-ish char-oriented peripherals like UARTs and I2C if you disallow nested interrupts to such peripherals.  This economises on stacks, allows simple FIFO comms from the interrupt-handlers for rx packets and enables the use of a shared pool of buffers for them.  The thread can wait on a semaphore for buffers on a thread-safe tx queue and a single, shared simple FIFO queue for rx buffers.  Whenever a thread queues up a buffer for tx, or an interrupt-handler has queued up an rx buffer, it signals the semaphore.